# Why translucent black screen appears on navigating back

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui

I am using Matial Motion for navigation Transition but on navigating back I got a black translucent screen.

[image]

Function using in `HomeScreen.kt`

```kotlin
 private fun navigateToAddLink(link: LinkModel? = null) {
        exitTransition = MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Y, /* forward= */ true)
        reenterTransition = MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Y, /* forward= */ false)
        findNavController().navigate(
            HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToAddLinkBookFragment(link),
        )
    }
```

here is `AddLinkBookFragment.kt`

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AddLinkBookFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_add_link_book) {

    private val binding: FragmentAddLinkBookBinding by viewBinding()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enterTransition = MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Y, /* forward= */ true)
        returnTransition = MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Y, /* forward= */ false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.apply {
        }
    }
}
```

Get the solution for my problem